# LNK2005 error because I have two c++ windows running parallel

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

I am working on a uni project with multiple tasks, and I am trying to debug a simple program, however I am getting the error "LNK2005 main already defined in task 1".

I realise this is because I have used "int(main)" for both tasks (I have code for task 1 and code for task 2). I do not want to have to create a new project folder for every task. Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Are the two "tasks" supposed to be run as separate programs? Then it makes sense to create them as separate projects within the workspace. If you have common code, you can either put that in a separate folder that both projects uses, or make a library project for the common code and then let the programs link with the library.

Comment: It's better if you include your code.

Comment: Otherwise, if each "task" is supposed to run as a separate thread within a single program, then you can create a single `main` function which creates the threads and then calls the "tasks" main-functions (which you have to rename to something appropriate).

Comment: @DaoXio Not in this case.

Comment: If that so, the second comment of Joachim is your best option.

Comment: It is not very clear what your "tasks" are. If they are separate independent assignments, then you should create a separate project for each one. If they are parts of the same program that must be run in parallel, as your title suggests, then it's may or may not be simple and you probably need to tell more about your exact problem.

Comment: My first task is a wages calculator , and second task is to see if a number is divisible by 5. they are both part of the same question sheet so I thought it would be best to keep them in the same folder, however if this is the case then should I keep it simple and create a new folder for each task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is generally advisable to have a project for each executable you build, you can get away with having a single project for multiple executables if you manage to somehow get rid of the undesired duplicate mains. You have quite a few options available to you:

1. Have only one main. Have it test its own executable name, and take specific action depending on the name it finds. In the post-build rules, set up rules for creating each (specifically named) executable from your base executable. This allows you to build all your executables at the same time in a fairly efficient manner.
2. Have multiple mains, but hide them using #ifdefs. Add a #define to the project settings or just somewhere above main(), and compile as needed. This is ok if you don't want to build all your executables all the time.
3. Just bite the bullet and set up multiple projects.

Whatever you do, consider that being able to build everything you have in a single step is considered a highly desirable trait of build systems, and is usually high on the list of features a properly engineered development process should have.

Comment: Thankyou very much , this explanation has really cleared things up for me !

Comment: Good answer! I'd like to add that while MSVS defaults don't provide that, you can put multiple project files into the same directory. That way they can share source files, for example. However, you will have to adjust a few directories in the configuration so that each project has its own output dir, intermediate dir and program database (plus others I forgot, it's been with MSVS 2005, IIRC). You can refer to variables of the form `$(ProjectName)` though to ease this task. Also, copying the project files requires you to delete their UUID, so MSVS generates a new one.